# Unable to fix position of two nodes in vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to fix the position of two nodes.
They should be on top of each other, 400px apart in the y-dimension.

```
var edges = [{
    id:"1",
    fixed: {x:true, y:true},
    x:0,y:-200
},{
    id:"2",
    fixed: {x:true, y:true},
    x:0,y:200
}, ...];
```

However, the position are not fixed and wander all over the place.
This is the corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucae91jh/1/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this workaround will work for you:

1) store nodes and edges in `dataSets`

2) set node positions on `afterDrawing` and update the `dataSet`

```
  network.on('afterDrawing', function(){
    let data = [{id: 1, x: 0, y:-200}, {id:2, x:0, y:200}];
    nodesObj.update(data);
  });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7juye694/