# In vis-network, how to align nodes on the same vertical position?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

This problem is driving me crazy

My requirement is simple, I want to put **node `x` and `y` on the same vertical position**. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340351/2142577) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786335/unable-to-fix-position-of-two-nodes-in-vis-js) question, the answer seem to suggest manually setting the x position. However I don't really want to do that, is there a better way?

https://jsfiddle.net/laike9m/dg8Lzt7c/31/

The following graph is what I currently have:

[image]

Ideally, I want the left part unchanged, but `y` is placed on the same vertical position with `x`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join them with a transparent edge:

```json
{
  "from": "x",
  "to": "y",
  "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, interestingly, if `hidden` is true, then the nodes are **not** aligned:  https://jsfiddle.net/laike9m/dg8Lzt7c/47/, however if it's false, nodes are aligned:  https://jsfiddle.net/laike9m/dg8Lzt7c/49/

Comment: My bad, I should've tested it. The edge can't be hidden but can be transparent.

Comment: Make sense. thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/laike9m/5gvh0ya4/2/ is a working example.